# Sound effects suggestions requested

Tags: sfx, sound-effects, sound-design, sampler, kontakt

Hi,

I am currently developping a sample foley/sound effects library for Kontakt, EXS24 and Structure and I'm looking for suggestions.

From your point of view, what would be useful and complementary to conventional sound effects libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Wait. You're using these sampler-powered sound libraries and looking for more? Or are you looking for suggestions for a sound library that you're developing?

Answer (score 1):

to your question, some useful sampler based fx libraries may include:

footsteps (obvious choice)

impact sweeteners, debris

gun shots and sweetening layers, gun handling

gadgetry and small servo patches

data/text on screen / typing / hi tech graphic fx

a nice instrument with effects and layers to easily create basic swooshes, transitions with the keyboard instead of spotting and editing library sounds.

rene and i's library have a few built for kontakt:
www.echocollectivefx.com

Comment: Hey thanks Brad. Footsteps is on production in june. Few collections are ready-to-go like Winter package, including over than 12 snowshoes on differents snow surfaces, winter clothes, snow footsteps, ect. Other collections from Kitchen sink (with faucet working with modwheel) to washing dishes, few power tools, trekking footsteps, ect. Lot of work do do! ;-)

Comment: sounds great Bernard, building them right does take time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Omnisphere. 
I think it might be a good complement. 
It combines synth and sample sounds in a very interesting way.

Comment: Here's an interesting factiod - If you read the Omnisphere end user licence agreement, it clearly says that you are not permitted to use Omnisphere for Sound Effects or Sound Design.  I'm not sure how Spectrasonics would police that though.

Comment: Thanks Javier but I was talking more about foley style sound effects like footsteps, clothing, household, impacts and so on. In fact, I would like to know if there is any needs for this. This said, like Bill said, we have to be carefull with licence agreement. Cheers.

Comment: @BillMellow The exact reason why I don't own spectrasonics products. There is sound design in music as well.... "Lets put out a product that is illegal to use in every way..." - Not really a cool thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, amazing there's still a distinction (in some people's minds) between sound design and music. I'd love to see the courtroom scene trying to identify the difference "The distinction between sound design and music is..." cue experts Chion, Murch & Sonnenschein... that would lead to a very long trial! 

Comment: Wow guys. I discovered the software in a studio where I was intern and I really liked it. Definetly I will have to research those license restrictions.

Comment: The difference is in how you're credited for the work? I guess Spectrasonics is happy when they get paying musicians overusing their sound design, but they aren't happy getting other sound designers overusing their sound design. As you may know, there's always the way around it by contacting them on a per use basis (and they tell you the price) and I believe some sound designers use that. It's just been made more difficult when the use is not in a music piece. I would really like to know the real reason behind this kind of licensing, but at the same time I think it sort of makes sense.

Comment: I THINK I read somewhere that in spectrasonics lingo "sound design" equal designing musical instruments/sounds to use in other instruments. Ie you are not allowed to. Rebate a sound, sample it and sell it as a contact patch. I do know that it has. Even used in several films as film sound design.
Personally I think it has a bit of recognisable character so I wouldn't use it. I prefer Alchemy to create my own stuff. 

Comment: Sorry, rebate=create... 
Has. Even=has been

Answer (score 0):

Seasonal winds
Emotional winds
Mechanical winds

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

Here's the final version of 2 Kontakt 3.02, Kontakt 4.2.4 (with GUI) and EXS24 footsteps patches. You need full retail Kontakt version.

[Dowload here for free](http://www.signo-sfx-instruments.com)